# my seeder doesn't store info in my database

Tags: database, laravel, seeding, laravel-seeding, laravel-7

I'm trying to seed my roles table for different roles in this company but when I run "php artisan migrate:fresh --seed" I  get no error messages but there is no data in my database.

```
<?php

use App\Role;
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class RoleSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        $roles = [
            [
                'name' => 'Admin',
            ],
            [
                'name' => 'Klant',
            ]
        ];

        foreach ($roles as $role){
            Role::insert([
                'name'  => $role['name'],
                'created_at' => now(),
                'updated_at' => now()
            ]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does the console output that your seeder has run? Have you added it to the `DatabaseSeeder.php`?

Comment: @kerbholz thanks for the info I forgot about that, I am new to laravel so thanks for the help

Answer (score 3):

You have to add any custom seeders to the `database/seeders/DatabaseSeeder.php` file as this is the file that gets called per default when you're seeding the database.

```
class DatabaseSeeder
{
    public function run() 
    {
        $this->call([
            RoleSeeder::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```